Upgrade app to .NET 8: Use "RollForward" instead?
I have a .NET 6 desktop application which isn't standalone, so it requires a .NET runtime installed on the user machine.
However, .NET 6 will reach end-of-support later this year. I'm planning to upgrade to .NET 8 as TargetFramework as usual, but I'm wondering if I should stay on TargetFramework .NET 6 and set RollForward to LatestMajor instead?
Shouldn't this allow for the latest security patches and improvements if the end-user has a new .NET 8 Runtime installed, but also still allow older users to stay on .NET 6? Otherwise there is always the hard break for them where my app will not work on user-side until they install the new .NET runtime version.
This thought came up, because using libraries which have TargetFramework set to older versions works without problems by default and makes sense because otherwise it would fragment the whole ecosystem if every library would have to be upgraded.

Roll-forward looks like the best answer if you wish to not affect how users configure their systems to run your app. However, this will keep you from patching security issues that arise from using outdated packages that need to support the older version of .Net.
My recommendation would be to create two versions of your application:

A deprecated version that users could still download and you would be able to support with some newer features later on that supports .Net 6. This version should also have a security notice that using it would not grant the user with up to date security patches.
A second, primary version, that only supports .Net 8 and later to allow those who are able to run the more secure version of .Net. This also allows you to update to newer more secure version of your dependencies as well.

This is how packages work in most workflows and allows users who need or can only run on lower versions to use your package in their project.

Regarding security patches, I'd like to dig a bit deeper here.
I've experimented that a .NET 6 app with RollForward will load all the System.*.dlls from .NET 8 if a .NET 8 runtime is installed.
Doesn't this mean that a .NET 6 app with RollForward will essentially benefit from the security updates of .NET 8 as long as that runtime is installed?

For the runtime, yes, but not for any NuGet packages that are installed, especially those called out specifically in you .csproj file. Many have a minimum .Net version, especially those created by Microsoft in which the major version must match the version of .Net being used.

I think I have contrary evidence: Looking at some Microsoft packages on NuGet.org (e.g. Microsoft.Extensions.Logging@8.0.0), then it seems this package is built for: net462, net6.0, net7.0, net8.0, netstandard2.0, netstandard2.1.
I've tried using that with an app targeting .NET 5 and that works, and uses actually the netstandard2.1 variant. So to me it appears that I can use the latest library version (8.0.0) still on even a .NET5 application.
